# R ggplot2: labels not in dodged position on geom_bar despite position = position_dodge(0.9)

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I'm trying to add data-labels on dodged geom_bar plot. I know about parameter: position = position_dodge(0.9). However, for some reason this doesn't work for me. Can anyone explain, what I'm doing wrong?

My code:

```
data_test <- data.frame(Country = c(rep("Poland",5), rep("Europe", 5)), 
           Year = c(rep(c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018),2)),
           value = c(0.38, 0.34, 0.38, 0.34, 0.51, 0.41, 0.40, 0.42, 0.33, 0.45))

ggplot(data_test) +
  geom_bar(aes(Year, value, fill = Country),
           position = "dodge", stat = "identity", width = 0.75) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(round((value), digits = 2)),
                x = Year, y = value + 0.05),
                size = 5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
```

Comment: You didn't tell `geom_text()` which variable you want to dodge on.  Either move `fill` to be a global aesthetic by moving it into `ggplot` or add `group = Country` into the `aes()` for `geom_text()`.

Comment: Your answer solves my problem. And my question is indeed a duplicate. I'm sorry, I didn't find it earlier on my own (I tried though, but overlooked it).